# Ubuntu WiFi is extremely slow and getting disconnected every few minutes

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I have been looking at different posts to figure out why the Wifi is so slow, but to no avail.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 just day before yesterday, and have a dual boot with Windows 10. Windows 10 is giving me normal speed,but when I try to login through Ubuntu I cannot get speed more than 40/50 KB's. I am attaching Wireless-info scripts output below, and would be glad to provide any other information necessary. Thanks.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 May 2017 23:31 AST +0300

Booted last: 25 May 2017 00:00 AST +0300

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, nomodeset, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7917]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              761856  4 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              581632  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    16384  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:69035 (69.0 KB)  TX bytes:69035 (69.0 KB)

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.100.5  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b02d:a1db:4f5f:7d19/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12307 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8742023 (8.7 MB)  TX bytes:4492794 (4.4 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Private"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Private' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:198   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       843     1  0 23:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         802.11n
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        USB WLAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8192cu
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-53-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/net/wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Private
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       bc8a390c-7044-4d03-9b44-0fdd4fcd9cb3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   bc8a390c-7044-4d03-9b44-0fdd4fcd9cb3 | Private
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.100.5/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.100.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.100.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1496003050
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 259200
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.100.5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.100.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.100.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.100.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.100.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.100.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::b02d:a1db:4f5f:7d19/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID     BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Private  <MAC 'Private' [AC1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  46      â–‚â–„__  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Gujjar]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Gujjar | type=wifi | permissions=user:ahsan:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Gujjar
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Private]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Private | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Private
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Riyadh (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Private' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=12/70  Signal level=-98 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Private"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000007be187ebb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 64ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Gujjar' [AC2]>
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Gujjar"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002a8d936184
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2348ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8xxxu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_bt.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B_NoBT.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_A.bin
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8XXXu USB mac80211 Wireless LAN Driver
author:         Jes Sorensen <Jes.Sorensen@redhat.com>
srcversion:     59F02B6CF781E1985E0D1CE
depends:        mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Set debug mask (int)
parm:           ht40_2g:Enable HT40 support on the 2.4GHz band (bool)
parm:           dma_aggregation:Enable DMA packet aggregation (bool)
parm:           dma_agg_timeout:Set DMA aggregation timeout (range 1-127) (int)
parm:           dma_agg_pages:Set DMA aggregation pages (range 1-127, 0 to disable) (int)

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7FD327046ED7ECB8EE1DA58
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     1CECA7FEE652ED4ABDA8A2B
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     FF42529D1B19DDAF0323975
depends:        rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B936ED0E7D6B2CC6861A1AE
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     9AF49B72127065FCF655D6A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-53-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     46F63B461AA5E38D042F531
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_pages: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_aggregation: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_timeout: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/ht40_2g: Permission denied
[rtl8xxxu]

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/E220x.conf]
options E220x fwlps=N

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="E220x"

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    1.690728] systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[    2.988671] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[    3.041559] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x11
[    3.070166] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[    3.070241] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[    3.070266] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[    3.072982] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    3.077602] rtl8192cu 3-5:1.0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from wlan0
[    3.219538] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link is not ready
[    3.222094] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[    3.233655] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[    3.626362] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[    5.555691] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: authenticate with <MAC 'Private' [AC1]>
[    5.576702] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: send auth to <MAC 'Private' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    5.581829] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: authenticated
[    5.583350] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: associate with <MAC 'Private' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    5.622632] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Private' [AC1]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[    5.722781] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: associated
[    5.722788] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link becomes ready
[    5.722851] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'Private' [AC1]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Change the wireless encryption settings, at the router, to WPA2-AES. TKIP and mixed mode work poorly.

Comment: I think they already are - I see WPA & WPA2 Personal under Network Management, Security.

Comment: From nmcli output: SECURITY - WPA1 WPA2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. Let's blacklist one and see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
exit
```

Any improvement? It might take a reboot.

Now, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly *not* TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: You are a life-saver my friend. Thank you! How did you know I had conflicting drivers?

Comment: I can see it in the data you posted. I have seen this a few times before. Glad it's working.