# WiFi is slow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless, tp-link

**NOTE**: This question can duplicate but most solution I tried didn't worked.

My kernel version is: **4.15.0.45** and I am using Ubuntu 16.04. The internet speed is much better in Windows.

Here is the output I got after running the wireless extension script

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Feb 2019 19:41 IST +0530

Booted last: 13 Feb 2019 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

1b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7a36]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. Media Keyboard K200
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8xxxu              122880  0
mac80211              778240  1 rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              622592  1 mac80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    24576  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp27s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp27s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.12/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 85380sec preferred_lft 85380sec
    inet6 fe80::3eb0:87ca:b97a:b16b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp27s0   no wireless extensions.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"buyBTC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:79   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.12  metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       920     1  0 19:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek 
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11n NIC 
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8xxxu
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     buyBTC 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       41731f3b-4a1b-4832-a96b-ebbbda1e210f
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   41731f3b-4a1b-4832-a96b-ebbbda1e210f | buyBTC 2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.12/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1550152488
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.12
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3eb0:87ca:b97a:b16b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:<MAC address>
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:39:e5:1b:7a:87:1d:44:1e:ae:ee:fb:15:c7:75:4c:23

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp27s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp27s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.2/0000:16:04.0/0000:1b:00.0/net/enp27s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
buyBTC  <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  36      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 
808     <MAC '808' [AN2]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/buyBTC 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=buyBTC 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:python:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=buyBTC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/buyBTC 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=buyBTC 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:python:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=buyBTC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/buyBTC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=buyBTC | type=wifi | permissions=user:python:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=buyBTC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country IN: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5350 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp27s0   no frequency information.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Failed to read scan data : Resource temporarily unavailable

enp27s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8xxxu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_bt.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B_NoBT.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_A.bin
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8XXXu USB mac80211 Wireless LAN Driver
author:         Jes Sorensen <Jes.Sorensen@gmail.com>
srcversion:     E7E78FAA920143C9B0CB35A
depends:        mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8xxxu
vermagic:       4.15.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug:Set debug mask (int)
parm:           ht40_2g:Enable HT40 support on the 2.4GHz band (bool)
parm:           dma_aggregation:Enable DMA packet aggregation (bool)
parm:           dma_agg_timeout:Set DMA aggregation timeout (range 1-127) (int)
parm:           dma_agg_pages:Set DMA aggregation pages (range 1-127, 0 to disable) (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     10B87D6D65DDD085D1326C9
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     62FD05DCC5AEEA290640C3D
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_pages: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_aggregation: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_timeout: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/ht40_2g: Permission denied
[rtl8xxxu]

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.597209] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp27s0: link is not ready
[    5.650858] r8169 0000:1b:00.0 enp27s0: link down
[    5.650949] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp27s0: link is not ready
[  202.833786] usb 1-2: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[  202.833919] usb 1-2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  211.184539] rtl8xxxu 1-2:1.0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from wlan0
[  211.224143] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[  235.621037] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: authenticate with <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]>
[  236.139821] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: send auth to <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  236.141313] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: authenticated
[  236.144152] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: associate with <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  236.149320] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'buyBTC' [AN1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  236.190419] usb 1-2: rtl8xxxu_bss_info_changed: HT supported
[  236.224021] wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: associated
[  236.304806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

**What I tried!!**

I checked the answer [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918942/ubuntu-wifi-is-extremely-slow-and-getting-disconnected-every-few-minutes) but that issue doesn't exist with me.

Another answer I **checked**(not tried) [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/883688/329001) but the problem is I don't see any wireless extension using `iwconfig` command [which is weird as the adapter is connected and net is working slowly]

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx503eaaad2171  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"buyBTC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A8:25:EB:D6:2A:49   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:171   Missed beacon:0

enp27s0   no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: "`3: wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500`" shows your MTU is too big. `sudo ifconfig wlx503eaaad2171 down;sudo ifconfig wlx503eaaad2171 mtu 1480;sudo ifconfig wlx503eaaad2171 up.`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I have switched to ethernet cable as I was too frustrated with trying new wifi adapters.